# Let $r_n : \mathbb{{N}^{n}} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ a fixed bijection. Show that $f$ is recursive iff $r_n \circ f \circ (r_k)^{-1}$ is recursive.

Tags: logic, computability

Let $r_n : \mathbb{{N}^{n}} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ a fixed bijection.

I have to show that $f : \mathbb{{N}^{k}} \rightarrow \mathbb{{N}^{n}}$ is recursive iff $r_n \circ f : \mathbb{{N}^{k}} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is recursive and iff $r_n \circ f \circ (r_k)^{-1} : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ is recursive too.

For the "left to right" side, I am tempted to use the fact that a composition of recursive function is also recursive. Can we make the jump from "fixed bijection" to "recursive" ? Namely is every fixed bijection necessarily computable ?

For the "right to left" side, I was thinking of using a proof by "contraposition", i.e. if $r_n \circ f$ is not recursive then by some properties $f$ would not be neither but I can't find any.

I am fairly new to this field and website therefore I would appreciate hints/solutions that doesn't involve too complex material.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say recursive, do you mean primitive recursive, total recursive, or are you including partial recursive? I have not seen a clean definition of just "recursive." BTW, not every fixed bijection is primitive recursive.  $$\left.\right.$$ Assuming you mean primitive recursive, $f$ must satisfy (at least) one of the five recursion axioms. Have you tried showing for each of those five cases that $r_n\circ f$ also satisfies one of the axioms?  And similarly for the other two implicatoins. Unless I have erred, this approach works if you mean "primitive rucursive."

Comment: I am not sure to which one of the aforementioned terms it corresponds to, but from my textbook it is defined as primitive recursive functions that can be "built" - using in addition of the basics functions - the minimization function, i.e. if $f(x,y)$ is recursive and regular for $y$ then $h(x)=min y (f(x,y)=0)$ is recursive too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it didn't occur to me indeed. Just to make sure I understand as some definitions are a bit blurry to me, what would be the idea, i.e. what do we want to prove if, for instance,  $f(n)=n+1$ ?

Comment: @MarkFischler "Recursive" in this context means the same thing as "total recursive". This matches Keron's definition in the previous comment. It is *not* the same as "primitive recursive", which is a more restricted notion.

Comment: What do you mean by "... iff ... and iff ..."? Should the second "iff" be there?

Comment: I have to prove a "double equivalence". It could also be formulated this way : "Show the following statements are equivalent 1) $f$ is recursive 2) $r_n \circ f$ is recursive 3) $r_n \circ f \circ (r_k)^{-1}$ is recursive"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true as stated; it is only true if the $r_n$ are required to be recursive.

You can see that the indicated property implies that $r_n$ is recursive by taking $k=n$ and $f$ equal to the identity function.

If you do assume that the $r_n$ are recursive, then each $r_n^{-1}$ is also recursive, and the statement follows immediately, using the fact that the composition of recursive functions is recursive.

Comment: Thanks, I feel it is the kind of reasoning expected. However I am not sure to understand how you prove that $r_n$'s are necessarily recursive. If I take $k=n$ and $f(n)=n$, what would be the contradiction if $r_n$ was not recursive ?

Comment: @Keron You're welcome.

Comment: Could you please elaborate slightly more on how the indicated property implies $r_n$ to be recursive with $k=n$ and $f$ the identity function ? I think I am missing something. Thanks for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: Assume that for every function $f\colon\mathbb{N}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^n,$ $f$ is recursive iff the function $r_n\circ f$ (which maps $\mathbb{N}^k$ to $\mathbb{N})$ is recursive.  Take $k=n,$ and let $f\colon\mathbb{N}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^n$ be the identity function. Since $f$ is recursive, $r_n\circ f$ must be recursive too; but $r_n\circ f=r_n.$

Comment: I actually had more difficulties with the fact that we generalize this result, but if I get it right, by taking $f$ identity and $n=k$ we don't lose generality.

Comment: This isn't a without-loss-of-generality situation. That part of the answer is only demonstrating that, for every $n,$ the statement$$(\forall k)(\forall f\colon\mathbb{N}^k\to\mathbb{N}^n)(f\text{ is recursive iff }r_n\circ f\text{ is recursive)}\tag{1}$$implies that$$r_n\text{ is recursive }\tag{2}$$(the purpose being to show that the problem as stated, without the assumption that the $r_n\text{'s}$ are recursive, was wrong.) To prove this implication, we pick particular values for $k$ and $f;$ we can do that because the hypothesis $(1)$ says that the statement is true for *all* $k$ and $f.$

Comment: Great explanation, clear and concise. I really thank you for your time.

Comment: You're welcome.